# Mousedown event on submit button messes with the default click behavior

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a partial view which has file inputs and a submit button.
When I try to disable my file inputs on click of my submit button, the HttpPostedFiles becomes null in the controller, I am new to Jquery so I guess this could be interfering with the default behavior of the submit button. 
When I do an unbind on click event, the whole thing gets undone, file inputs become enabled again.
Hence, I tried to disable my file inputs on mousedown of my submit button, same problem reappeared.
When I remove this code, I get the posted files.

My view contains:

```
@{ Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, 
new { id  "fileUploader",enctype  "multipart/form-data" });}

<div>
<table>
<tr><td><label for="file1">Filename:</label>           
<input type="file" name="files" id="file1" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><label for="file2">Filename:</label>         
<input type="file" name="files" id="file2" /></td></tr>     
<tr><td>  <input type="submit" id="btnUpload" name="Command" Value="Upload"/> </td></tr> </table>
</div>
@{ Html.EndForm();}
```

My script file contains:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#btnUpload').click(function (e) {
        $('#file1').attr('disabled', true);
        $('#file2').attr('disabled', true);


    });
});
```

Any ideas how can I disable my file inputs (input type = "file") without the submit button behavior being messed up?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why do you do it in mousedown ? do it in the click ?

Comment: Disabled form elements are not send when submitting a form – so you will have to disable them _after_ your form is send.

Comment: can you provide us with any code you tried?

Comment: @CBroe - can you give me an example where they disabled the controls after submit? Any event which gets fired post submit or so?

Comment: @Bellash: I have edited my question to include code I tried.

Comment: @codebrain - I have tried to that in click first but as the posted files where coming null so I was just checking with mousedown but now I realize the problem is due to disabled file inputs as CBroe has suggested.

Comment: I resolved the issue by disabling the click event of the file input on click of the submit button like so...                                                   $('#file1').on("click", false);
        $('#file2').on("click", false);
        
        $('#file1').css("opacity", "0.5");
        $('#file2').css("opacity", "0.5");

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by disabling the click event of the file input on click of the submit button, instead of disabling the whole control, I also made it translucent so that the user gets the feel it is disabled.

```
$('#file1').on("click", false);
    $('#file2').on("click", false);

    $('#file1').css("opacity", "0.5");
    $('#file2').css("opacity", "0.5");
```

Disabling the whole control was making the posted file null.